# tidy from broom not finding method for LDA from topicmodels

Tags: r, broom, topicmodels

Running this script, straight from 'Text mining with R',

```
library(topicmodels)
library(broom)

data("AssociatedPress")
ap_lda <- LDA(AssociatedPress, k = 2, control = list(seed = 1234))
tidy(ap_lda)
```

I get this error message:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
>    cannot coerce class "structure("LDA_VEM", package = "topicmodels")" to a >data.frame
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In tidy.default(ap_lda) :
>    No method for tidying an S3 object of class LDA_VEM , using as.data.frame

```
packageVersion("broom")
```

> ‘0.4.3’

```
packageVersion("topicmodels")
```

> ‘0.2.7’

```
sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] broom_0.4.3       topicmodels_0.2-7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] NLP_0.1-11        Rcpp_0.12.15      compiler_3.4.3    pillar_1.1.0      plyr_1.8.4
 [6] bindr_0.1         base64enc_0.1-3   keras_2.1.3       tools_3.4.3       zeallot_0.1.0
[11] jsonlite_1.5      tibble_1.4.2      nlme_3.1-131      lattice_0.20-35   pkgconfig_2.0.1
[16] rlang_0.1.6       psych_1.7.8       yaml_2.1.16       parallel_3.4.3    bindrcpp_0.2
[21] stringr_1.2.0     dplyr_0.7.4       xml2_1.2.0        stats4_3.4.3      grid_3.4.3
[26] reticulate_1.4    glue_1.2.0        R6_2.2.2          foreign_0.8-69    tidyr_0.8.0
[31] purrr_0.2.4       reshape2_1.4.3    magrittr_1.5      whisker_0.3-2     tfruns_1.2
[36] modeltools_0.2-21 assertthat_0.2.0  mnormt_1.5-5      tensorflow_1.5    stringi_1.1.6
[41] slam_0.1-42       tm_0.7-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tidytext`package appears to be extending some of the methods used in the `broom` package...

So using the `tidy` function from `tidytext` does work:

```
broom::tidy(ap_lda, matrix = "beta")

Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("LDA_VEM", package = "topicmodels")" to a data.frame
In addition: Warning message:
In tidy.default(ap_lda, matrix = "beta") :
  No method for tidying an S3 object of class LDA_VEM , using as.data.frame

tidytext::tidy(ap_lda, matrix = "beta")

# A tibble: 20,946 x 3
   topic term                                        beta
   <int> <chr>                                      <dbl>
 1     1 aaron      0.00000000000169                     
 2     2 aaron      0.0000390                            
 3     1 abandon    0.0000265                            
 4     2 abandon    0.0000399                            
 5     1 abandoned  0.000139                             
 6     2 abandoned  0.0000588                            
 7     1 abandoning 0.00000000000000000000000000000000245
 8     2 abandoning 0.0000234                            
 9     1 abbott     0.00000213                           
10     2 abbott     0.0000297                            
# ... with 20,936 more rows
```

When I have loaded `tidytext` : `library(tidytext)` then this works automatically for me without specifying .i.e. `tidy(ap_lda, ...)`. I can see from your session info that `tidytext` is not loaded.

Answer (score 2):

For future me coming across this when running into the same problem again:

Where Henderson's solution does not work, be more specific and use `tidytext:::tidy.LDA`