# Using tidytext and broom but not finding tidier for LDA_VEM

Tags: r, broom, tidytext

The tidytext book has examples with a tidier for topicmodels:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(topicmodels)
library(broom)

year_word_counts <- tibble(year = c("2007", "2008", "2009"),
+                            word = c("dog", "cat", "chicken"),
+                            n = c(1753L, 1157L, 1057L))

animal_dtm <- cast_dtm(data = year_word_counts, document = year, term = word, value = n)

animal_lda <- LDA(animal_dtm, k = 5, control = list( seed = 1234))

animal_lda <- tidy(animal_lda, matrix = "beta")

# Console output
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("LDA_VEM", package = "topicmodels")" to a data.frame
In addition: Warning message:
In tidy.default(animal_lda, matrix = "beta") :
  No method for tidying an S3 object of class LDA_VEM , using as.data.frame
```

Replicating the error which is also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638405/tidy-from-broom-not-finding-method-for-lda-from-topicmodels) but in this instance `library(tidytext)` is 
 present.

Below is a list of all packages are their corresponding version:

```
 packageVersion("tidyverse")
 ‘1.2.1’

 packageVersion("tidytext")
 ‘0.1.6’   

 packageVersion("topicmodels")
 ‘0.2.7’  

 packageVersion("broom")
 ‘0.4.3’
```

Output from function call `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] broom_0.4.3       tidytext_0.1.6    forcats_0.2.0     stringr_1.2.0     dplyr_0.7.4       purrr_0.2.4       readr_1.1.1       tidyr_0.8.0      
 [9] tibble_1.4.2      ggplot2_2.2.1     tidyverse_1.2.1   topicmodels_0.2-7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] modeltools_0.2-21 slam_0.1-42       NLP_0.1-11        reshape2_1.4.3    haven_1.1.1       lattice_0.20-35   colorspace_1.3-2  SnowballC_0.5.1  
 [9] stats4_3.4.3      yaml_2.1.16       rlang_0.1.6       pillar_1.1.0      foreign_0.8-69    glue_1.2.0        modelr_0.1.1      readxl_1.0.0     
[17] bindrcpp_0.2      bindr_0.1         plyr_1.8.4        munsell_0.4.3     gtable_0.2.0      cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_0.3.2       psych_1.7.8      
[25] tm_0.7-3          parallel_3.4.3    tokenizers_0.1.4  Rcpp_0.12.15      scales_0.5.0      jsonlite_1.5      mnormt_1.5-5      hms_0.4.1        
[33] stringi_1.1.6     grid_3.4.3        cli_1.0.0         tools_3.4.3       magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.1    janeaustenr_0.1.5 crayon_1.3.4     
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.1   Matrix_1.2-12     xml2_1.2.0        lubridate_1.7.2   assertthat_0.2.0  httr_1.3.1        rstudioapi_0.7    R6_2.2.2         
[49] nlme_3.1-131      compiler_3.4.3
```

Answer (score 6):

Deleting .Rhistory and .RData led to correct behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that is extremely mysterious to me. I am not able to reproduce that error. I installed to all the same versions/etc as you, except that I am on MacOS instead of Windows. I do have [tests for the LDA tidiers that run and pass](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-lda-tidiers.R) on Windows on Appveyor, so I would expect this to work.

The code you have should work without loading **broom**, for what it's worth.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(topicmodels)

year_word_counts <- tibble(year = c("2007", "2008", "2009"),
                           word = c("dog", "cat", "chicken"),
                           n = c(1753L, 1157L, 1057L))

animal_dtm <- cast_dtm(data = year_word_counts, document = year, term = word, value = n)

animal_lda <- LDA(animal_dtm, k = 5, control = list( seed = 1234))

class(animal_lda)
#> [1] "LDA_VEM"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "topicmodels"

tidy(animal_lda, matrix = "beta")
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    topic term                                                beta
#>    <int> <chr>                                              <dbl>
#>  1     1 dog     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  2     2 dog     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  3     3 dog     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  4     4 dog     1.00                                            
#>  5     5 dog     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  6     1 cat     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  7     2 cat     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  8     3 cat     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#>  9     4 cat     0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#> 10     5 cat     1.00                                            
#> 11     1 chicken 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#> 12     2 chicken 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#> 13     3 chicken 1.00                                            
#> 14     4 chicken 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
#> 15     5 chicken 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000372
```

Created on 2018-02-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

What happens if you load `library(methods)` as well?

Comment: I tried two combinations: without Broom, and without Broom but with Method. Both combinations gave the same error.

Comment: This was also happening on another Windows PC. I tried deleting .Rhistory and .RData. On both PCs, the code then ran correctly. On the second machine I tried this, I noticed that before the deletion, when RStudio was opening the project, I would get a message "loading required package topicmodels". After deletion of the two files, the loading message went.

Comment: Are you saving your workspace as .Rdata between sessions? I wonder if something wacky is going on with that... For the record, I strongly encourage all R users to move away from such a workflow: http://stat545.com/block002_hello-r-workspace-wd-project.html#workspace-and-working-directory

Comment: Not usually, but does happen. No more!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the very helpful answer provided by Julia Silge:

I too believe that the interaction between loading .Rdata and the topicmodels package is the culprit here. But you can still work with your saved workspace:

I was able to eliminate the problem by starting with a fresh restart of RStudio, loading the topicmodels package and **then** loading the .Rdata. Done in this sequence, the error message disappears. Loading first the data and then the package does not work.

One more word on workspaces: In the case of LDA, using these along with your RScripts is really the only way I could figure out to work efficiently. Depending on the parameters and the size of the corpus, fitting an LDA-model may take several hours. It is crucial to be able to save the model fit to then do further analyses down the road.

Comment: I often use RDS files in such cases:

`saveRDS(animal_lda, "animal_lda.rds")
animal_lda <- readRDS("animal_lda.rds")`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I loaded the LDA I had saved.
Finally, for no apparent reasons when I restarted the R session I worked again.